# Confused about while loop / indexOf()

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm going through the book Beginning Javascript, and in it there's an example which uses a while loop that returns how many times the word "Wrox" is in a string.

```
var myString = "Welcome to Wrox books. " + 
               "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. " + 
               "Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox";

var foundAtPosition = 0;
var wroxCount = 0;

while (foundAtPosition != -1) {
    foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox", foundAtPosition);

    if (foundAtPosition != -1) {
        wroxCount++;
        foundAtPosition++;
    }
}

document.write("There are " + wroxCount + " occurrences of the word Wrox");
```

Somehow it returns 4, but it seems like it should return a much higher number. Why isn't wroxCount larger? Like each of these being an occurrence

> W -> Wrox | wroxCount = 1
>
> We -> Wrox | wroxCount = 2
>
> Wel -> Wrox | wroxCount = 3
>
> Welc -> Wrox | wroxCount = 4
>
> Welco -> Wrox | wroxCount = 5
>
> Welcom -> Wrox | wroxCount = 6
>
> Welcome -> Wrox | wroxCount = 7

all the way to the r in first Wrox then behaving the same before finding the second, third and fourth Wrox. Why is wroxCount only 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why wroxCount **is** and **should be** 4 is the second argument to indexOf is a start position

on each iteration of the loop, the start position is set to the last located index of the word Wrox + 1, so each loop after the first starts looking for the word Wrox at the rox bit of the previous match

if you scan the string, there are indeed four occurrences of the word Wrox (wrox doesn't match as this is a case sensitive match)

```
foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox", foundAtPosition);
```

foundAtPosition will be the index of the word Wrox in myString, the parameter fed IN to the indexOf function will be the result of the previous match (+1)

Comment: Aha!!! I totally missed what `foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox", foundAtPosition);` was doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression for it

```js
var myString = "Welcome to Wrox books. " + 
                   "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. " + 
                   "Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox";

alert(myString.match(/Wrox/g).length)
```

OR If you want to find in lower case match also then

```js
var myString = "Welcome to Wrox books. " + 
                       "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. " + 
                       "Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox";

    alert(myString.match(/Wrox/ig).length)
```

Comment: This is a book example, I just don't understand how it works really. Like how it knows there's only 4 occurrences of "Wrox"? How does the while loop know that it was indexed already?

Answer (score 1):

Upper and lower cases doesn't match. You need to convert strings to the equal case. Try this:

```
var myString = "Welcome to Wrox books. " + 
           "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. " + 
           "Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox";

var foundAtPosition = 0;
var wroxCount = 0;

while (foundAtPosition != -1) {
foundAtPosition = myString.toLowerCase().indexOf("Wrox".toLowerCase(), foundAtPosition);

if (foundAtPosition != -1) {
    wroxCount++;
    foundAtPosition++;
}
}

document.write("There are " + wroxCount + " occurrences of the word Wrox");
```

Comment: This is a book example, I just don't understand how it works really. Like how it knows there's only 4 occurrences of "Wrox"? How does the while loop know that it was indexed already?

Answer (score 0):

I think your program should return 5 and not 4, but not a much higher number. There are 5 occurrences of the word wrox in your string.

As another answered pointed out, you have to correct for upper and lower case.

```
foundAtPosition = myString.indexOf("Wrox".toLowerCase(), foundAtPosition);
```

Besides that, the program functions as intended. One the first loop, it searches the entire original string for the word wrox. It keeps track of the the location of the first occurrence within the string. On the second go around, it searches the string again. This time, the search is limited from the first occurrence of the word wrox until the end of the string. It then keeps track of the second occurrence of wrox. And it keeps doing this until it cannot find the word anymore.